# How to pass firstname to homepage by indetification login user

Tags: reactjs

im totaly new in react , i want to pass username or firstname that in database in welcome (username or firstname) by indetifying the login user. if the login with "aaaa" then welcome aaaa or the firstname from aaaa
i dont know how to pass it from login to dashboard i already tried to call function dashboard still same. i want to pass from login to admin navbar

index.js

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        post : [],
        formData : {
          email : '',
          password: '',
          first_name : ''
        },
        isLogedIn : false

      }
      this.handleForm = this.handleForm.bind(this);
      this.submitLogin = this.submitLogin.bind(this);
    }

    getPostAPI = () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/datadiri')
      .then((res) => {
          this.setState ({
              post : res.data
          })
      })
    }

    handleForm = (e) => {
      let formDataNew = {...this.state.formData};
      formDataNew[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
      this.setState({
        formData : formDataNew
      })

    }

    submitLogin = () => {
      const { dispatch } = this.props;
      const {post} = this.state;    
      if(post.find(e =>  `${e.email}${e.password}` === `${this.state.formData.email}${this.state.formData.password}` )) {
        dispatch(userLogin(this.state.formData.email, this.state.formData.password));
              customHistory.push('/admin/index');
      }else  {
        alert("Email atau Password Salah!");
        this.setState ({
          formData : {
            email : '',
            password: ''
          },


        })

      }
    }


    componentDidMount () {
      this.getPostAPI();
    }
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';

import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.jsx";
import AuthLayout from "layouts/Auth.jsx";
import reducer from './components/reducers'

const store = createStore(reducer);
const customHistory = createHashHistory();


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
      <Router history={customHistory}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/auth" render={props => <AuthLayout {...props} />} />
          <Redirect from="/" to="/auth/login" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

routes

```
mport Index from "views/Index.jsx";
import Profile from "views/examples/Profile.jsx";
import Maps from "views/examples/Maps.jsx";
import Register from "views/examples/Register.jsx";
import Login from "views/examples/Login.jsx";
import Tables from "views/examples/Tables.jsx";
import Icons from "views/examples/Icons.jsx";

var routes = [
  {
    path: "/index",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: "ni ni-tv-2 text-primary",
    component: Index,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    path: "/icons",
    name: "Icons",
    icon: "ni ni-planet text-blue",
    component: Icons,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    path: "/maps",
    name: "Maps",
    icon: "ni ni-pin-3 text-orange",
    component: Maps,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    path: "/user-profile",
    name: "User Profile",
    icon: "ni ni-single-02 text-yellow",
    component: Profile,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    path: "/tables",
    name: "Tables",
    icon: "ni ni-bullet-list-67 text-red",
    component: Tables,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    icon: "ni ni-key-25 text-info",
    component: Login,
    layout: "/auth"
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: "Register",
    icon: "ni ni-circle-08 text-pink",
    component: Register,
    layout: "/auth"
  }
];
export default routes;
```

adminnavbar

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
// reactstrap components
import { Container } from "reactstrap";
// core components
import AdminNavbar from "components/Navbars/AdminNavbar.jsx";
import AdminFooter from "components/Footers/AdminFooter.jsx";
import Sidebar from "components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx";

import routes from "routes.js";

class Admin extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(e) {
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
    this.refs.mainContent.scrollTop = 0;
  }
  getRoutes = routes => {
    return routes.map((prop, key) => {
      if (prop.layout === "/admin") {
        return (
          <Route
            path={prop.layout + prop.path}
            component={prop.component}
            key={key}
          />
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };
  getBrandText = path => {
    for (let i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
      if (
        this.props.location.pathname.indexOf(
          routes[i].layout + routes[i].path
        ) !== -1
      ) {
        return routes[i].name;
      }
    }
    return "Brand";
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Sidebar
          {...this.props}
          routes={routes}
          logo={{
            innerLink: "/admin/index",
            imgSrc: require("assets/img/brand/argon-react.png"),
            imgAlt: "..."
          }}
        />
        <div className="main-content" ref="mainContent">
          <AdminNavbar
            {...this.props}
            brandText={this.getBrandText(this.props.location.pathname)}
          />
          <Switch>{this.getRoutes(routes)}</Switch>
          <Container fluid>
            <AdminFooter />
          </Container>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Admin;
```

Comment: As you are using `redux`, you can store the name in state and use whenever you want. What is the issue in using redux state?

Comment: so how to store? im totally new :'( . i just want to understand react js

Comment: Simple what you can do is when login is success dispatch the login action with user data to redux store and change the route to your desired route. The component related with redirected route should check the redux store for the user data and display them accordingly. 
Go through the redux documentation as well. They way you implemented redux in components is wrong.

[link](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start)

Answer (score 0):

When your user logging in, if the user logged in successfully before you redirect user just save his user somewhere, one of your options is saving users data in local storage like this

```
localStorage.setItem("user", user);
```

The first "user" is a name that you define, the second user is your argument that you get users info, so it creates a data in your browser storage and you can use it in other pages.
So in your welcome page, just use this  :

```
Const user=localStorage.getItem("user");
```

And in your render just make a div and write

> welcome {user}

I hope you get the idea and it works well for you.
Ps. If you use chrome you can inspect your page and go to the application tab and see your saved data in local storage.

Comment: what is OP bro ?

Comment: still not success